# Select only the 1 data but the number of rows is still 3

Tags: sql

Is there a way for this?

From:

```
(Select  MBLNo,HBLNo from tblCargo where MBLNo = 'M00000001' )

1 | M00000001 | H0003
2 | M00000001 | H0003
3 | M00000001 | H0003
```

To:

```
1 | M00000001 | H0003
2 | NULL      | H0003
3 | NULL      | H0003
```

Comment: Your sample data shows three columns, but your SELECT statement only contains two columns. Where does the first column come from?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think this is better done in the application that displays the data, it is possible in SQL:

```
select id, 
       case 
         when row_number() over (partition by mblno order by id) = 1 then mblno 
         else null 
       end as mblno
from tblcargo
where ...
```

Comment: OP didnt mention the rdbms

Comment: @TimSchmelter: that is standard ANSI SQL (the tag `sql` refers to that) and all [modern DBMS](http://modern-sql.com/) support window functions

Comment: I didn't know that MySql supports `row_number`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: nobody is talking about MySQL - only "SQL" (at least so far)

Comment: You were talking about _all_ modern rdbms. There is a great chance that OP is using it(2nd most widespread and especially for learning purposes).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I don't consider MySQL a "modern" DBMS. It's still lacking many modern SQL features (although window functions and recursive queries are _finally_ coming in the next release)

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MBLNO ORDER BY MBLNo) rno
     FROM temp)
     SELECT CASE
                WHEN rno = 1
                THEN MBLNo
                ELSE NULL
            END AS MBLNO,
            HBLNo
     FROM CTE;
```

**Desired Output :**

```
MBLNo       HBLNo
M00000001   H0003
NULL        H0003
NULL        H0003
```